# Magento2 How to Add placed order Product Quantity in Sales order grid in Backend

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database

I want add placed order quantity tab in sales order grid in magento2 backend . Please let me know the solution . I have already done maximum process but it not works what i did , i don't know where i am wrong .

Thanks for advance .

Comment: can you update the question with your code

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create file like sales_order_grid.xml, and within that place the code like:-

```
<columns name="sales_order_grid_columns">
        <column name="cust_qty" class="Vendorname\Custom\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Qty">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qty</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
```

Now create the file at the defined location, and extend it to Column and use the `prepareDataSource` for your further processing.

You should write your code, that way anyone will be able to help you out.